# USB flash drives doesn't show up but ports are working

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

My USB flash drives do not show up when I connect it to my USB ports. The USB ports are working fine because I can connect other USB devices such as mice, printers etc and they are working fine.

The USB flash drives themselves work if I test them on another PC.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This question is lacking details needed for anyone to be able to help you. Please add details of what you have tried so far and ***which OS you are using***. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: This PC where these storage devices are not working, are they connected to a personal or corporate network. It is trivial to disable mass storage devices but allow I/O devices like the ones you listed.